# Browser Uploads to S3 using HTML POST Forms with Signature Version 4

Tags: python-3.x, forms, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am currently trying to rebuild the browser upload to s3 found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/de/articles/browser-uploads-to-s3-using-html-post-forms/). However, I always get an error saying `The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.`. I found several answers here on StackOverflow but no one seemed to do it with just a form and python and so I am still stuck with the problem.

That's my current HTML code: ( I censored the access key, the signature, and policy and the real bucket)

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>S3 POST Form</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <form action="https://some-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="uploads/${filename}"> <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="ACCESSKEY">
        <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="private">
        <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://www.google.de">
        <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="SOMEPOLICY">
        <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="SIGNATURE">
        <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">
        <!-- Include any additional input fields here -->
        File to upload to S3: <input name="file" type="file">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I calculate the policy and signature with the help of a python script beforehand: (again copied from the article, I just set the expiration date from 2009 to 2019)

```
import base64
import hmac, hashlib
import json

policy_document = {"expiration": "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z", "conditions": [ {"bucket": "some-bucket/"}, ["starts-with", "$key", "uploads/"], {"acl": "private"}, {"success_action_redirect": "http://www.google.de"}, ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""], ["content-length-range", 0, 1048576]]}

s = json.dumps(policy_document)


policy = base64.b64encode(s.encode('utf-8'))

print('POLICY: ', policy)

key= 'ACCESSKEY'

signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(key.encode('utf-8'), policy, hashlib.sha256).digest())

print ('SIGNATURE: ', signature)
```

Basically, it's exactly the code from the AWS [article](https://aws.amazon.com/de/articles/browser-uploads-to-s3-using-html-post-forms/) but I still get this error.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Are you using Access Key ID (incorrect) or Secret Access Key (correct)? You are using sha256 instead of sha1.

Comment: @JohnHanley It is the same error if I change it to sha1. I tried changing it to "SHA256" because that's what it says in the error msg. I used the "Access key ID", i am now using the secret access key but the error is again the same

Comment: It has been a while since I wrote code for AWS signing, but I think that article is ancient. Some AWS regions now require AWS V4 signing. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html

Comment: Your article was Last Updated: March 4, 2018, so I guess it is OK. However, test against us-east-1. Once that works then if you get an error, in a bucket in Germany for example, about V4 you will now why.

Comment: @JohnHanley it works with us-east-1!!! So if it does not work with EU bucket, I have to use the AWS V4 signing you which mentioned before?

Comment: Correct. AWS is transitioning to V4 signing. New regions, as of three or four years ago, do not support the older signature.

Comment: Here is a link on V2 signing, which also shows which regions require V4 which means they do not support V2. All regions support V4 now which is safer and more secure. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html